# How to delete duplicates, but aggregating sums of repeated rows (Python or Excel)

Tags: python, excel

For example, I have a **Symbol** and **Quantity** columns.

```
AAA 1000000
AAA 1000000
AAA 1000000
BBB 5000000
CCC 1000000
CCC 1000000
```

To essentially look like

```
AAA 3000000
BBB 5500000
CCC 2000000
```

Attempt after Rayhane's suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df['Quantity'] = df.groupby(['Symbol']).transform('sum')
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

What's weird is that it looks like the code worked, but the number of rows remain the same. (5000 lines, I would've expected it to drop to something like 2000). Can someone verify my code?

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: are you willing to use pandas library ?

Comment: yes, i was wondering if there was a simple command in pandas package actually

Comment: also, i apologize for bad formatting. first time posting! should look better now.

Comment: do you need help reading from your excel file to a dataframe as well or is that taken care of ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750590/pandas-groupby-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can do this:

```
df['Quantity'] = df.groupby(['Symbol']).transform('sum')
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

documentation:

[transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

[groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

[drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

input:

```
  Symbol  Quantity
0    AAA   1000000
1    AAA   1000000
2    AAA   1000000
3    BBB   5000000
4    CCC   1000000
5    CCC   1000000
```

now if you print(df):

```
  Symbol  Quantity
0    AAA   3000000
3    BBB   5000000
4    CCC   2000000
```

you can even [reset the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) if you want:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

output becomes:

```
  Symbol  Quantity
0    AAA   3000000
1    BBB   5000000
2    CCC   2000000
```

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the answer if it suited your needs for future users @hiimarksman